# testing observable after store update with runInAction

Tags: jestjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to test a simple store, basically to test values of observable after a store update:

```
class UserStore {

  @observable user = {userName:'', source: '', lastLocation: ''};

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this);
  }

  async updateUserInformation(
    options
  ) {
    try {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.user = { ...this.user, ...options };
        console.log(this.user);//i can see updated values here.
      });
    } catch (error) {}
  }

}
```

UserStore.test.js

```
import UserStore from './UserStore';

describe('UserStore', () => {
  it('should update store information partially', async () => {
    const store = new UserStore();
    const newInfo = {
      lastLocation: 'westLands'
    };
    await store.updateUserInformation(newInfo);
    expect(store.user.lastLocation).toStrictEqual(newInfo.lastLocation);
  });

});
```

The test fails because lastLocation is still empty.

Comment: Well, this is super weird indeed, it should work, your code looks correct and fine. Does it work outside of the test in your App?

Comment: @Danila yes it works just fine.

Comment: It might be something with the way jest compiles to code (because of the decorators).